# set https for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, https

I want to use HTTPS for tomcat. so i make .keystore and uncomment connector in server.xml and restart tomcat service , and port 8443 is opened but when insert my address :
https://my_ip:8443
in address bar of my browser , page just working and search and try and nothing shows up and page never stop and ....
 i could not see the tomcat page .

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="password"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Comment: Are you running Tomcat as `root`? Quoting [Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/security-howto.html#Non-Tomcat_settings): *Tomcat should not be run under the root user.* If not running as root, then it likely doesn't have permission to file `.keystore` in the `/root` home directory. Check Tomcat log files (`catalina*`) for errors during startup.

Comment: thanks for your answering. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/.keystore (Permission denied) where i supposed to put the .keystore file ? not to happen this error?

Comment: Thanks.The problem is solved. I copied the .keystore file in my tomcat directory and i changed the path of .keysore file in server.xml file and restart my tomcat  and bingo!!!!! It works now.